# The amount of Xcode tasks increase after every build

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode10, xcode10.1

Since I'm using Xcode 10.0, the amount of tasks which Xcode is building increases every time when I build the project. To reset the amount of tasks I have to clear the project. Can anyone else retrace this issue? The main problem is, that the build time increases with the amount of tasks.

[image: Build 2]

[image: Build 1]

**EDIT**

Same behavior in Xcode Version 10.1 (10B61)

Comment: I would assume cyclical dependencies with many generics. Did you try to switch compilation mode from "Incremental" to "Whole module"?

Comment: Not yet! How can I do it?

Comment: Go to Build Settings and insert in search field 'SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE'.

Comment: That does change my amount of tasks from 3500-ish to 24. So seems good. But I would still like to understand the issue, you have some ideas?

Comment: For me, there is no effect after changing to "Whole module". Understanding the issue can help.

Comment: This still happens in Xcode 11.7 and it is unlikely because of cyclical dependencies. It happens on the default "command line" project with either Swift or C++. Just add a newline to the main source file, hit build and the number goes up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]Xcode 10 introduced a new build system, and it's not without bugs. I was able to reproduce the ever-increasing task count the same way you did. That's a lousy bug!
[release_notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes/build_system_release_notes_for_xcode_10)
To fix it search "User Header search paths" in build setting, and set it as NO

Comment: I have edited my answer, now you can find a picture for this setting

Comment: I tried this solution in Xcode 11.1(11A1027) and the long total build time didn't change and the number of tasks still increased from time to time.

Comment: It is not a Bool to set.
According to Documentation, 
This is a list of paths to folders to be searched by the compiler for included or imported user header files (those headers listed in quotes) when compiling C, Objective-C, C++, or Objective-C++. Paths are delimited by whitespace, so any paths with spaces in them need to be properly quoted. See `ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS` for more details on how this setting is used. If the compiler doesn't support the concept of user headers, then the search paths are prepended to the any existing header search paths defined in `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`.

Answer (score 1):

[Rishi Indolia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8486572/rishi-indolia)'s answer **in conjunction** with disabling the automatic reloading of views in the storyboard is what did it for me.

[image: disabling the automatic reloading of views in the storyboard]